# When click select tag why IE does not deselect text in input

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, select, input

I have a input text and a select tag in HTML.
I input something in input tag and select text, but when I click select tag to select something, IE does not deselect text in input tag.
Is  this IE's specification?
Can I use JavaScript to deselect text in input tag?
[image]

```
<input type="text" />
<br>
<select>
<option>aaaaa</option>
<option>bbbbb</option>
<option>ccccc</option>
<option>ddddd</option>
</select>
```

Comment: maybe you have active focus?

Comment: Can you please provide your code so i can make a couple of test and help you? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

```
window.document.onmousedown = mousedownControl;
function mousedownControl(e) {
    e = window.event;
    if (e.srcElement.nodeName == "SELECT") {
        document.selection.empty();
    }
}
```